# How to fix object transform when exporting from Blender to Godot

Tags: animation, 3d, blender, godot

Last night I made a model and animation in Blender 3.4 which, as many before, broke on export (glTF 2.0) to Godot 3.5.1. All parts of the knife are scattered and misaligned. I've spent hours trying to fix it but my limited understanding of the Blender workflow has me stumped.

**[This is what the animation is supposed to look like:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F6NPe.gif)**

**[And this is what it looks like in Godot:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QFoW7.gif)**

The closest I've gotten to fix the knife's alignment is as shown in the comparison picture below. The meshes for the knife's blade and handles had transform values far above 0 inside Godot. I changed these values to 0, which brought all the parts closer to the hand. Unfortunately, they're still misaligned both in terms of translation and rotation. I've tried manually adjusting the position of each mesh for the start of the animation, but so far this has proven equally messy in part due to strange rotation points. I have also applied transform to the meshes and armatures, but this seemingly makes no difference unless I also apply scale, which breaks the model similarly to the last gif.

[Comparison picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o8XE5.jpg)

I'm not sure if this is a Godot issue or a Blender issue, but any help is greatly appreciated. I'd love to know what I'm doing wrong so I can be more efficient and avoid these headaches in the future.

[.glb file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Z13V0rygY2g8xYXR-zq5TvFzmNWwjDGb/view)

[.blend file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uLOMUtJpSFPQsx47qvtBzk9zI1jzbuM4/view)

Thank you for reading.

Comment: It looks to me that Godot is importing the animation wrong. Perhaps can be fixed on Blender side. But I'm going to suggest you post to https://github.com/godotengine/godot/issues and let them have a look.

Comment: It seems that selecting "Use current frame" under "Animation" in the export menu solves the problem.